# Unable to send POST request with custom header and data in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to send post request to the server with custom header and data but server recieves empty object on android. I'm using axios 0.18.0 and react-native 0.57.8

```
const Feedback  = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchingData(true));
        axios.post(url, {x: 'x'}).then(res => {
            dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(true));
            dispatch(feedback(res.data));
        }).catch(err => {
            dispatch(fetchDataFailure(err));
        });
}
```

and header for axios :

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] ="Bearer " + e;
```

I tested and this is not a server problem. I also tried to send it by fetch.

Comment: And you have the same problem with fetch?

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem. I am facing the exact problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the config for header and add it inside Feedback

```
const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
            }
        };
    const Feedback  = () => {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(fetchingData(true));
            axios.post(url, config).then(res => {
                dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(true));
                dispatch(feedback(res.data));
            }).catch(err => {
                dispatch(fetchDataFailure(err));
            });
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I think there is some limiting on android when sending a post reacuest with custom header.I want to find  work around.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass headers as third argument to api call,

```
const Feedback = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchingData(true));
    axios.post(
        url,
        { x: "x" },
        {
          headers: {
            authorization: "your authorization"
          }
        }
      )
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(true));
        dispatch(feedback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(fetchDataFailure(err));
      });
  };
};
```